# Add image id to image path based on condition

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

I want to write xslt where I need to append the imagecode to image path based on chartcategory , below is not working for me, I think I am on wrong steps, I am not sure how to append imagecode to image path even

```
<MonthlyReport>
 <MonthlyImages>
     <ChartCategory>rankingSavingsPotential</ChartCategory>
     <ImageCode>30032327</ImageCode>
     <ChartCategory>Potential</ChartCategory>
     <ImageCode>34534556</ImageCode>
   </MonthlyImages>
</MonthlyReport>




<xsl:template match="/MonthlyReport">
   <html>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>
         <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="MonthlyImages/ChartCategory= rankingSavingsPotential">
           <img><xsl:attribute name="src=/Assets/images/<xsl:value-of select="ImageCode"/></img>
         </xsl:when>
         </xsl:choose>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
   </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "not working"? Do you get any error message? Does the transformation fail or not? Also, you need to show a _complete_ XSLT stylesheet and a complete, small XML input sample.

Comment: I am not able to see the image, placed complete xslt

Comment: The XSLT you show now is not even syntactically valid. Please fix the syntax first.

Comment: edited, please look into it now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a wild guess, but I think what you want is

**XSLT Stylesheet (1.0)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/MonthlyReport">
        <html>
            <table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                <tr>
                    <td width='100%'  class='cssLogo'>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="MonthlyImages/ChartCategory = 'rankingSavingsPotential'">
                                <img>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                        <xsl:text>/Assets/images/</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('server1/assets/images/image.aspx?ImageCode=',MonthlyImages/ImageCode)"/>
                                </img>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

I am glad to add explanations once we've established that this is what you need. Then, the result is:

**HTML Output**

```
<html>
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
         <td width="100%" class="cssLogo"><img src="/Assets/images/">30032327</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</html>
```

Comment: my image path should be http://server1/assets/images/image.aspx?ImageCode=3453454 , here I want to pass the imagecode value dynamically as xml element